# How to change vowel's color separately from consonant?

Tags: delphi, colors, delphi-7, arabic, delphi-xe5

In Arabic language, vowel combined with consonant makes one word. However, in Windows vowels can not be colored without consonants separately.

If you try to change the color of vowel's font, nothing happens. You must select consonants and vowels together and apply the font color. The same happens also in Microsoft Word, btw.

In Arabic language, especially for educational purposes, it's very common to show vowels with different color but Windows doesn't take this into account.

For better understanding of structure of the Arabic language see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet) from Wikipedia.

```
    // In Delphi 7 and Delphi XE5
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with RichEdit1 do begin
    Text:='بِسمِ اللّه‏ِ  '; // Add Arabic Text
    SelStart:=1;           // Select one vowel
    SelLength:=1;
    ShowMessage(SelText);
    SelAttributes.Color:=clRed; // try to change color
  end;

end;
```

Example of this problem in picture:

[image]

Comment: I understand your story, but it's unclear what exactly the question is. It sounds like a general complaint. Do you have a (Delphi) application where this is a problem? If you could please post some code, preferably a complete but as minimal as possible test project, then we can have a look.

Comment: Also, which Delphi version are you using? There might be a completely different solution depending on whether you use 2009 up or an older version.

Comment: There is, essentially, no support for this type of behaviour.  You can't even really do this with HTML [see, ex](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/different-font-colours-for-accent-marks-in-unicode).  You might be able to do this with a LaTeX renderer, if one exists for Delphi?

Comment: Please don't use JPG for non-photographic images.

Answer (score 0):

After month of research i found the solution.
Problem explained in [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/how-to-change-vowels-color-separately-from/7b26c660-6d63-4fbd-83fb-6000f4d5dbc9?auth=1).
Solution explained in [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm) and [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner).

For example i resolve this problem in Delphi:
I add a HTML Viewer free component to my form. Then i search for vowels. When i found a word with diacritic َ[ُ-] then i change string something like this:

```html
<span>ب&zwj;<span style="color:red;">ٌ</span>&zwj;ا</span>
```

The problem will be solved.